# Waring's problem with pairwise coprime summands

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

According to https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2019SL.pdf (p.100, Problem N7, Comment 2) for any $\alpha > 0$ there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that there are infinitely many positive integers which cannot be written as a sum of $n^{\alpha}$ (or fewer) pairwise coprime $n$-th powers.

Has anyone seen more around this - such as whether we can replace $n^{\alpha}$ by e.g. $2^n$?

Comment: I was thinking of contacting the author of the problem and saw the unfortunate news that he has passed away at age of 26 just two months after I posted the problem here :(